# Doctrine 2 Pagination with Association Mapping

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, associations

I am wondering **how can you paginate the results obtained from an entity association mapping in Doctrine 2?** For example

```
class Customer {
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Order")
   */
  private $orders;
}
```

can be used as such:

```
$customer->getOrders();
```

which will return a collection of `Order` objects.

The problem is when there are a large number of order objects.

We can use `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator` when building custom queries, however I do not see any way to hook into query generation when utilising association mapping.

```
class Paginator {
  /** 
   * @param Query|QueryBuilder $query A Doctrine ORM query or query builder. 
   */
  function __construct(
    //....
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same situation here, but with no desire to work on custom Paginator class I've just added methods to my Entity repositories that give out Paginator friendly DQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the EXTRA_LAZY fetch mode, Doctrine will not retrieve all objects when hydrating the collection. It will only retrieve the subset needed when you use the slice() method on the collection.

```
class Customer {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Order", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $orders;
}

$cust = new Customer;
$orders = $cust->getOrders()->slice(100, 50);
```

You would need to verify how this interacts with the pagination.

Comment: Thanks Louis-Philippe. I did not know about *extra lazy* assocations and think they could well be the way to go. There is pagination out of the box for Query and QueryBuilder objects so I might have to look at writing a custom adapter.

Comment: It would be nice for collection filters to know some SQL/DQL, so you could prepare filter for records, and then fetch them with slice. (current collection->slice() fetches all the data)

Answer (score 0):

Collections have a filtering API that allows to slice parts of data from a collection. If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to large collections. [Doctrine Filtering Collections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

```
class Customer {
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Order")
   */
  private $orders;

  public function getOrders($offset = 0, $limit = 30){

    $criteria = Criteria::create()
                ->setFirstResult($offset)
                ->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $this->orders->matching($criteria);

  }

}

$cust = new Customer;
$orders = $cust->getOrders(50, 100);
```